# Selecting button as a whole

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a navigation, and I am having a bit of trouble to select a button that I have divided with 2 a tags as a whole.

I want the button to completely highlight on active state, but instead it only either highlight the right of the button or the left of the button, please see below, link4 is the one I am interested in having it highlight as a whole including the arrow to the right.

[image]

```js
$('.arrow-up').on('click', function() {
    $('i.fa', this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
});

$('.bookmarks a').click(function(){
  var id = $(this);

  $('.bookmarks').find(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(id).addClass('active');
  localStorage.setItem('selectedolditem', id);
});

var selectedolditem = localStorage.getItem('selectedolditem');

  if (selectedolditem !== null) {
    $(selectedolditem).siblings().find(".active").removeClass('active');
    $(selectedolditem).addClass('active');
  }
```

```css
.bookmarks {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 162px; 
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  border:1px solid #D3D3D3;  
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
}

.bookmarks .nav li {
    background-color: #999999;
    width: 160px;
}

.bookmarks .nav li a {
    font-size: 13px; 
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #D3D3D3;   
}

.products-bookmarks ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.products-bookmarks nav li:hover {
    color: inherit;
}

.products-bookmarks ul li a:hover {
    color: inherit;
}

.bookmarks li li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none; 
}

.bookmarks .link4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #1e4056;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-bottom: 0; 
}

.dbl-link-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.bookmarks .link4 .left-side {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  flex: 0 0 calc(79%); 
}

.bookmarks .link4 .right-side {
    padding: 13px 0 12px 0;
}

.bookmarks .link4 .right-side {
  flex: 0 0 calc(20%); 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.bookmarks .link4 .left-side  span {
    padding: 15px;
}

.bookmarks .fa-chevron-down,
.bookmarks .fa-chevron-up {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px; 
}


.bookmarks .nav .link4 a {
  border-left: none;
}

.bookmarks .link4 .right-side a {
  border-bottom: none; 
}

.bookmarks .link4 .first-tree {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none; 
}


.bookmarks .first-tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree a {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree li a {
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #33b3ca;
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.bookmarks .double-btn .left-side {
  padding: 9px 9px 9px 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  flex: 0 0 calc(79%);
}

.bookmarks .double-btn .right-side {
  flex: 0 0 calc(20%);
  padding: 0;
}

.bookmarks .double-btn .fa-chevron-down,
.bookmarks .double-btn .fa-chevron-up {
  position: relative;
  top: 19px;
  left: 10px;
}

.bookmarks .double-btn ul {
  flex: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0px;
  list-style-type: none; 
}

.bookmarks .first-tree li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree .double-btn {
  padding: 0; 
}


.bookmarks .left-side .left-link {
  padding: 13px 0 12px 0; 
}


.bookmarks .double-btn .right-side a {
  padding: 0;
}


.bookmarks .second-tree li {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.bookmarks .second-tree li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* HOVER DISPUTES */
.bookmarks .first-tree li:first-child:hover {
    background-color: #efefef;
    opacity: : .60;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree li:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.bookmarks ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: .6;  
}

.bookmarks .second-tree li:first-child:hover,
.bookmarks .second-tree li:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: : .9;
}

/* ACTIVE STATE AND TRIANGLE */
.bookmarks li:active {
  position: relative;
  /*background-color: none;*/
  
}

.active
 {
    background-color: #2c3e50 !important;
    color: #fff !important;                
    opacity: 1 !important;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bookmarks" id="affix-nav"> 
        <ul class="nav top-menu" id="affix-ul">
          <li>
              <a href="#">
              Link 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              Link 2
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="#">
              Link 3
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="link4">
            <div class="dbl-link-wrapper">
              <a href="#" class="left-side">
                <span>Link 4</span>
              </a>  
              <a href="#" class="arrow-up right-side" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hiddenMenuOne">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">
                </i>
              </a> 
            </div>
            <ul id="hiddenMenuOne" class="collapse first-tree">
              <li>
                <a href="#">SubLink 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">SubLink 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">SubLink 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">SubLink 4</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">SubLink 5</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">SubLink 6</a>
              </li>
              <li class="clearfix double-btn">
                  <div class="dbl-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link left-link left-side">
                    Sublink 7
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="right-side arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hiddenMenuTwo">
                      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">
                      </i>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                <ul id="hiddenMenuTwo" class="collapse second-tree">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level - Link 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level - Link 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level - Link 3</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>   
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: take a look at the jQuery .closest function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change:

```
$(id).addClass('active');
```

with:

```
id.siblings().addBack().addClass('active');
```

This means: add siblings to current id and so add class for the whole button.

The snippet:

```js
$('.arrow-up').on('click', function(e) {
  $('i.fa', this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
});

$('.bookmarks a').on('click', function(e) {
  var id = $(this);

  $('.bookmarks').find('.active').removeClass('active');
  id.siblings().addBack().addClass('active');
  //localStorage.setItem('selectedolditem', id);
});
```

```css
.bookmarks {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 162px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  border:1px solid #D3D3D3;
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
}

.bookmarks .nav li {
  background-color: #999999;
  width: 160px;
}

.bookmarks .nav li a {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #D3D3D3;
}

.products-bookmarks ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.products-bookmarks nav li:hover {
  color: inherit;
}

.products-bookmarks ul li a:hover {
  color: inherit;
}

.bookmarks li li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.bookmarks .link4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #1e4056;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.dbl-link-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.bookmarks .link4 .left-side {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  flex: 0 0 calc(79%);
}

.bookmarks .link4 .right-side {
  padding: 13px 0 12px 0;
}

.bookmarks .link4 .right-side {
  flex: 0 0 calc(20%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.bookmarks .link4 .left-side  span {
  padding: 15px;
}

.bookmarks .fa-chevron-down,
.bookmarks .fa-chevron-up {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;
}


.bookmarks .nav .link4 a {
  border-left: none;
}

.bookmarks .link4 .right-side a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.bookmarks .link4 .first-tree {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}


.bookmarks .first-tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree a {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree li a {
  border-bottom: none;
  color: #33b3ca;
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: block;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.bookmarks .double-btn .left-side {
  padding: 9px 9px 9px 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  flex: 0 0 calc(79%);
}

.bookmarks .double-btn .right-side {
  flex: 0 0 calc(20%);
  padding: 0;
}

.bookmarks .double-btn .fa-chevron-down,
.bookmarks .double-btn .fa-chevron-up {
  position: relative;
  top: 19px;
  left: 10px;
}

.bookmarks .double-btn ul {
  flex: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree .double-btn {
  padding: 0;
}


.bookmarks .left-side .left-link {
  padding: 13px 0 12px 0;
}


.bookmarks .double-btn .right-side a {
  padding: 0;
}


.bookmarks .second-tree li {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.bookmarks .second-tree li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* HOVER DISPUTES */
.bookmarks .first-tree li:first-child:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
  opacity: : .60;
}

.bookmarks .first-tree li:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.bookmarks ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: .6;
}

.bookmarks .second-tree li:first-child:hover,
.bookmarks .second-tree li:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: : .9;
}

/* ACTIVE STATE AND TRIANGLE */
.bookmarks li:active {
  position: relative;
  /*background-color: none;*/

}

.active
{
  background-color: #2c3e50 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="bookmarks" id="affix-nav">
    <ul class="nav top-menu" id="affix-ul">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Link 1
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Link 2
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#">
                Link 3
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="link4">
            <div class="dbl-link-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="left-side">
                    <span>Link 4</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="arrow-up right-side" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hiddenMenuOne">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">
                    </i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul id="hiddenMenuOne" class="collapse first-tree">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 6</a>
                </li>
                <li class="clearfix double-btn">
                    <div class="dbl-link-wrapper">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link left-link left-side">
                            Sublink 7
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="right-side arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hiddenMenuTwo">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">
                            </i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <ul id="hiddenMenuTwo" class="collapse second-tree">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Third Level - Link 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Third Level - Link 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Third Level - Link 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @gaetanoM, that worked, will review jQuery Documentation to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Your on click listener is adding active class only to the link that is clicked (either left or right portion of the button).
Ideally you should be listening to onClick event of wrapper of the links, and adding active to the wrapper it self. 
But if you must apply the class to links within wrapper, here is something you can try:

```
$('.dbl-link-wrapper').click(function(){
  var id = $(this);
 $('.bookmarks').find(".active").removeClass("active");
 $(id).find('a').addClass('active');
 localStorage.setItem('selectedolditem', id);
});
```

Similar Pen I created for understanding:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgJRvM

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.bookmarks a').click(function() { 
        $('.bookmarks a').addClass('active');
    });
});

<!---css for activ button--->
.bookmarks li a:active{
   background: your background color;

}

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="bookmarks" id="affix-nav"> 
            <ul class="nav top-menu" id="affix-ul">
              <li>
                  <a href="#">
                  Link 1
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  Link 2
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="">
                <a href="#">
                  Link 3
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="link4">
                <div class="dbl-link-wrapper">
                  <a href="#" class="left-side">
                    <span>Link 4</span>
                  </a>  
                  <a href="#" class="arrow-up right-side" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hiddenMenuOne">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">
                    </i>
                  </a> 
                </div>
                <ul id="hiddenMenuOne" class="collapse first-tree">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 3</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 4</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 5</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">SubLink 6</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="clearfix double-btn">
                      <div class="dbl-link-wrapper">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link left-link left-side">
                        Sublink 7
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="right-side arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hiddenMenuTwo">
                          <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">
                          </i>
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    <ul id="hiddenMenuTwo" class="collapse second-tree">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level - Link 1</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level - Link 2</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level - Link 3</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>   
            </ul>
          </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```